# How to make the input placeholder same colour as div colour using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and I need to change the placeholder colour so its same colour as the div's colour using CSS.

But I can't seem to figure this out.

I've tried this code:

```
.form::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #999;
  opacity: .5;
}

.dob{
    color:#999 !important;

    font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

and it didn't work.

I'm also trying to achieve the same of the select option with no success.

changing the `opacity` doesn't seem to have any affect either.

Can someone please advice on this:

```css
.form .row {
height:auto;
}

.form .row {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width:90%;
}

.form input[type="text"], .form input[type="password"], .form textarea, .form input[type="email"], .form input[type="tel"], .form select, .form .dob{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.9);
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}






.form::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #999;
  opacity: .5;
}

.dob{
 color:#999 !important;

 font-size:14px;
 text-align:left;
}

select{
 color:#999 !important;

 font-size:14px;
 text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="#">
 
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="fancy-text" id="fancy-text" placeholder="Full Name"/>

  </div>
 
 
      <div class="row">
 
 <div class="dob" id="fancy-text5" placeholder="Date Of Birth">Date of Birth</div>
 
 

  </div>
 
  </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: @EternalHour indeed it does

Answer (score 0):

The following code may work:

```
.form::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```